# How to count "straight only" on poker

Tags: probability, combinatorics

In a usual poker hand, I would like to calculate the probability that one has a straight.

Without royal straights or flushes. I am comfortable with straight forward counting such as $nCr$ and $nPr$ and stuff, but this is giving me trouble.

Can anyone help ?

P.S.

For consistency, I would like to consider any combination of 10JQKA to be a royal straight.
I will also consider QKA23 a straight as well, so that a loop is accepted.

Comment: Does a royal straight mean any AKQJT?

Comment: can a straight be QKA23?

Comment: That is a curious definition of straight, but we can use it.  So you are rejecting AKQJT (because it is a royal straight but not a straight).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

number of straight flushes: $4*10$ (call this $A$)

number of royal straights:$4^5$ (call this $B$)

number of straight royal flushes: aka royal flushes: $4$ ($A\cap B$)

Number of straights: $4^5*10$ (call this U)

Number of straigh only hands: $4^5*10-4*10-4^5+4=9180=U-(A+B-(A\cap B)$

Comment: Could you explain me how you got straight flushes, royal straights and straights ?

Comment: a straight flush is uniquely determined by the color and the low card. The low card can be any card from 2 to queen (10 options).

Comment: a royal straight is determined by the symbol of the four cards in order) there are 4 possibilities for each one and 5 cards tat need to be chosen.

Comment: Every straight is determined by 2 things: first of all, the lowest card. second of all the symbol  of each one of those cards. there are 10 possibilities for the low card, and 4 possibilities for the sign of each card.

Comment: That was actually very helpful ! thanks

Comment: @Asinomás out of curiosity, why is it 4^5 then?

Comment: 10 options for the starting card and 4 options for the color of each of the 5 cards.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming a royal straight is any AKQJT and you want to exclude them, this is a good candidate for the [inclusion-exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)  Count all the straights, deduct the royal straights, deduct the straight flushes, note that you have deducted the royal flushes (suited AKQJT) twice, so add them back in once

Comment: That does make sense and I am fully aware of it, thank you. The problem is, I am having trouble identifying the total number of straights and straight flushes.

Comment: To get the number of straights:  how many ranks are there that can be the highest in a straight?  For a straight flush, all the cards must be the same suit.  For a straight, the cards can be any suits.  In fact, you can avoid excluding royal straights just by saying the Ace cannot be the highest card of a straight.